# Does C have a [[nodiscard]] mechanism to warn when values are ignored?

Tags: c

In C++ we can decorate our return types with "[[nodiscard]]" which triggers a compiler warning if the results are unused.

This is particularly useful to enforce error codes

```
auto dont_forget_to_check = do_something_important();
assert(dont_forget_to_check);
```

Does something like this exist for C?

Comment: I don't think it's in the standard, but may be available as implementation extensions.

Comment: Most compilers will have flags to enable such warnings. For example, gcc has `-Wunused-but-set-variable` that would probably work in this case.

Comment: @kaylum could be a valid answer

Comment: Possibly. But it is not quite the same. Because the attribute is more fine grained than the compiler flag so not sure whether that fully meets your needs. And it is compiler specific whereas your question may be interpreted to be asking about the C language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no standard way to do this, but gcc does support the `warn_unused_result` attribute for this.

```
__attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))
int foo()
{
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o x1 x1.c
x1.c: In function ‘main’:
x1.c:11:8: warning: ignoring return value of ‘foo’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     foo();
        ^
```

Answer (score 5):

> Does something like this exist for C?

Not yet, but likely in [C2x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x).

[C++11 style attribute syntax and the `nodiscard`, `maybe_unused`, `deprecated`, and `fallthrough` attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features).

Answer (score 1):

As of C23 you can use the [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes/nodiscard) attribute on functions, structs, unions and enums.

I tested it with GCC 13 and Clang 16, compiling with `-std=c2x` or `-std=gnu2x`.

```c
[[nodiscard]]
int fn();

struct [[nodiscard("warning message")]] S;
```

The second example doesn't warn when returning S* from a function.

No warning option is needed. The warning can be suppressed with `-Wno-unused-result`, and Clang will also suppress it with `-Wno-unused`.

If you want to write a macro that replaces it by the gcc attribute when the C standard used is lesser than C23, you can test for `__STDC_VERSION__ < 202000`.